# How to join 3 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server and I have 3 tables.

Students in a school, each one of these students has a hobby and each one of these students has a preferred colour too.

I want a table that shows each one of these student with their hobbies and preferred colours in the same table, where hobbies and colours are next to each other and not duplicated.

**Students**

```
StID Name
---------
101  Mike
102  Nancy
103  Tom
104  Lisa
105  John
106  Matt
```

**Hobbies**

```
StID Hobby   PracticeDate
-------------------------
101  Bikes   12/2/2024
101  Music   24/2/2024
101  Movies  14/3/2024
102  Art     13/2/2024
102  Music   23/2/2024
103  Soccer  21/3/2024
103  Drawing 04/4/2024
103  Movies  22/2/2024
105  Music   11/2/2024
105  Bikes   26/3/2024
```

**Colours**

```
StID Colour   PaintingDate
--------------------------
101  Blue     30/5/2024
101  Green    01/4/2024
102  Yellow   20/4/2024
102  Black    18/3/2024
102  Green    29/2/2024
103  Black    26/3/2024
103  Yellow   11/2/2024
103  Red      30/3/2024
104  Blue     07/2/2024
104  Pink     24/2/2024
```

I want the result to be like this

```
StID   Name   Hobby   PracticeDate   Colour   PaintingDate
-----------------------------------------------------
101  Mike     Bikes   12/2/2024      Blue     30/5/2024
101  Mike     Music   24/2/2024      Green    01/4/2024
101  Mike     Movies  14/3/2024      
102  Nancy    Art     13/2/2024      Yellow   20/4/2024
102  Nancy    Music   23/2/2024      Black    18/3/2024
102  Nancy                           Green    29/2/2024
103  Tom      Soccer  21/3/2024      Black    26/3/2024
103  Tom      Drawing 04/4/2024      Yellow   11/2/2024
103  Tom      Movies  22/2/2024      Red      30/3/2024
104  Lisa                            Blue     07/2/2024
104  Lisa                            Pink     24/2/2024
105  John     Music   11/2/2024     
105  John     Bikes   26/3/2024     
106  Matt
```

I tried joining the tables but that did not work as expected.

```
SELECT 
    p.StID,
    p.Name,
    ph.Hobby,
    ph.PracticeDate,
    lr.Colour,
    lr.PaintingDate
FROM 
    Students p
LEFT JOIN 
    Hobbies ph ON p.StID = ph.StID
LEFT JOIN 
    Colours lr ON p.StID = lr.StID
```

Code to create tables and insert records

```
-- Create Students table
CREATE TABLE Students (
    StID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
);

-- Insert data into Students table
INSERT INTO Students (StID, Name) VALUES
(101, 'Mike'),
(102, 'Nancy'),
(103, 'Tom'),
(104, 'Lisa'),
(105, 'John'),
(106, 'Matt');

-- Create Hobbies table
CREATE TABLE Hobbies (
    StID INT,
    Hobby VARCHAR(50),
    PracticeDate DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (StID) REFERENCES Students(StID)
);

-- Insert data into Hobbies table
INSERT INTO Hobbies (StID, Hobby, PracticeDate) VALUES
(101, 'Bikes', '2024-02-12'),
(101, 'Music', '2024-02-24'),
(101, 'Movies', '2024-03-14'),
(102, 'Art', '2024-02-13'),
(102, 'Music', '2024-02-23'),
(103, 'Soccer', '2024-03-21'),
(103, 'Drawing', '2024-04-04'),
(103, 'Movies', '2024-02-22'),
(105, 'Music', '2024-02-11'),
(105, 'Bikes', '2024-03-26');

-- Create Colours table
CREATE TABLE Colours (
    StID INT,
    Colour VARCHAR(50),
    PaintingDate DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (StID) REFERENCES Students(StID)
);

-- Insert data into Colours table
INSERT INTO Colours (StID, Colour, PaintingDate) VALUES
(101, 'Blue', '2024-05-30'),
(101, 'Green', '2024-04-01'),
(102, 'Yellow', '2024-04-20'),
(102, 'Black', '2024-03-18'),
(102, 'Green', '2024-02-29'),
(103, 'Black', '2024-03-26'),
(103, 'Yellow', '2024-02-11'),
(103, 'Red', '2024-03-30'),
(104, 'Blue', '2024-02-07'),
(104, 'Pink', '2024-02-24');
```

Comment: Try using `ISNULL` and `CONVERT` to correct display issues. What output are you getting?

Comment: How do you know what order to list hobbies and Colors?

Comment: Use an `order by` clause?

Comment: @SeanLange order does not matter, put them in any order

Comment: How do you match hobbies with colors?

Comment: @jarlh no match, they are separate.. i just want to list them together in one query

Comment: You still haven't showed us what your current query is returning.

Comment: Also you are an experienced user of the site, so you should be providing your sample data as DDL+DML

Comment: Or, even better, provide a fiddle (e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk)

Comment: @DaleK I added DDL and DML

Comment: You still haven't showed the results you are currently getting

Comment: [Write a title that summarizes the specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Write%20a%20title%20that%20summarizes%20the%20specific%20problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd request but the query isn't all that complicated. Here is one solution. I am using a pair of ctes to join the Students table with the respective interest. Then simply a full outer join between those two will return the results you are after.

```
with HobbyList as
(
    select s.StID
        , s.Name
        , h.Hobby
        , h.PracticeDate
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by s.StID order by h.PracticeDate) 
    from Students s
    left join Hobbies h on h.StID = s.StID
)
, ColourList as
(
    select s.StID
        , s.Name
        , c.Colour
        , c.PaintingDate
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by s.StID order by c.PaintingDate) 
    from Students s
    left join Colours c on c.StID = s.StID
)

select StID = coalesce(h.StID, c.StId)
    , Name = coalesce(h.Name, c.Name)
    , Hobby = h.Hobby
    , PracticeDate = h.PracticeDate
    , Colour = c.Colour
    , PaintingDate = c.PaintingDate
from HobbyList h
full outer join ColourList c on c.StID = h.StID and c.RowNum = h.RowNum
order by coalesce(h.StID, c.StId)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is almost worked, except the last record of 106 did now show up.

Comment: That's because that student does not have any hobbies or colours. This is an easy fix. Just the joins in both ctes to left joins and it will show up. I edited my answer with the left joins.s

Answer (score 1):

You can join both `hobby` and `colour` to the `student` table separately, generate a row_number for each `StID` in each derived table/subquery, and then join on `StID` and that row number using `FULL OUTER JOIN` to achieve this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ph.StID, lr.stID) StID,
    COALESCE(ph.Name, lr.Name) Name,
    ph.Hobby,
    ph.PracticeDate,
    lr.Colour,
    lr.PaintingDate
FROM (
        SELECT s.StID,
            s.Name,
            h.Hobby,
            h.PracticeDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY h.StID
                ORDER BY Hobby
            ) as rn
        FROM Hobbies h
            INNER JOIN Students s ON s.sTID = h.StID
    ) ph
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT s.StID,
            s.Name,
            c.Colour,
            c.PaintingDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY c.StID
                ORDER BY Colour
            ) as rn
        FROM Colours c
            INNER JOIN Students s ON s.sTID = c.StID
    ) lr ON ph.StID = lr.StID
    AND ph.rn = lr.rn
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/0la_UkTz